# Is it possible to reduce dom size on wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i take care about [famefact](https://famefact.com) website. i tried to optimize the loading time. But pagespeed tells me i got an excessive amount of DOM paramenters are there any tricks to reduce this for page speed?
thanks

i tried to install some wordpress plugins with no sucesss.

Comment: Using builder on large content page will give you this warning unless you code your own modules to minimize the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You have a complex carefully wrought single-page app here, with lots of animations and other effects. You implement that via a DOM with many elements. Your most straightforward path to reducing that number of elements is to remove some functionality or information from the single-page app and move it to other pages.

You could also consider eliminating animations and other such "sugar" from the app to get a simpler DOM.

That being said, your biggest speedup opportunity lies in your .mp4 files.